# Fragment with DialogDataPicker

Tags: android, android-fragments

my application have a simple NavigationDrawer with fragment.The problem comes when I try to launch DialogDataPicker on 'EditText (android: id = "@ + id / GiornoOre) into the Fragment_ore_permesso. Without the fragment I do it as follows:

```
 public class RegisterActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener, OnFocusChangeListener{
    public Context c;

    private DatePickerDialog BirthdayDatePickerDialog;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
    //

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        edt_birthday = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ITALY);  
        edt_birthday.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        setDateTimeField();

        }



    private void setDateTimeField() {
        edt_birthday.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        BirthdayDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.DatePickerStyle, new OnDateSetListener() {
            //     BirthdayDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                edt_birthday.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }

        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        BirthdayDatePickerDialog.setTitle("");

    }
}
```

but the problem is when I'm in a fragment because the setOnFocusChangeListener () takes as a parameter a Listener... and... this is my Fragment:

```
public static class Fragment_ore_permesso extends Fragment {
    //TODO inserire il calendario in permesso ore

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private View rootView;
    private ImageView img_Ore;
    private TextView nome_Dip_ore;
    private TextView nome_ore;
    private EditText cliente_ore;
    private EditText responsabileInternoOre;
    private TextView tipologiaRichiestaOre;
    private Spinner spinnerOre;
    private EditText giornoOre;
    private EditText numeroOre;
    private Button bt_send_Ore;
    private String ore;
    private Ore mOre;

    //gestioneDatapicker
    private DatePickerDialog OreDatePickerDialog;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;



    public static Fragment_ore_permesso newIstanceOrePermesso(int sectionNumber){
        Fragment_ore_permesso fragment = new Fragment_ore_permesso();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public Fragment_ore_permesso (){ }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("fragment_ore_permesso", "onCreateView");
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ore_permesso,container, false);

        setView();

        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ITALY);
        giornoOre.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);


        setDateTimeField();

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity(), R.array.ore,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerOre.setAdapter(adapter);
        ore =((Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerOre)).getSelectedItem().toString();

        setInfoOre();

        bt_send_Ore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Boolean change = false;
                if(!cliente_ore.getText().toString().equals(UserIstance.getIstanceUserIstance().getClienteUser()) &&
                        !cliente_ore.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    UserIstance.getIstanceUserIstance().setClienteUser(cliente_ore.getText().toString());
                    change = true;
                }
                if(!responsabileInternoOre.getText().toString().equals(UserIstance.getIstanceUserIstance().getResponsabileInternoUser())){
                    UserIstance.getIstanceUserIstance().setResponsabileInternoUser(responsabileInternoOre.getText().toString());
                    change = true;
                }
                if(change){
                    CharSequence pswErrata= "La richiesta delle ore di permesso è stata inoltrata! ";
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), pswErrata, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    private void setInfoOre() {
        String NomeCognomeUser = UserIstance.getIstanceUserIstance().getNomeUser()+" "+ UserIstance.getIstanceUserIstance().getCognomeUser();
        nome_ore.setText(NomeCognomeUser);
        if(!UserIstance.getIstanceUserIstance().getClienteUser().equals(""))
            cliente_ore.setText(UserIstance.getIstanceUserIstance().getClienteUser());
        if(!UserIstance.getIstanceUserIstance().getResponsabileInternoUser().equals(""))
            responsabileInternoOre.setText(UserIstance.getIstanceUserIstance().getResponsabileInternoUser());
    }

    private void setView() {
        img_Ore = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageOre);
        nome_Dip_ore = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Nome_Dip_ore);
        nome_ore =(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Nome_ore);
        cliente_ore =(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Cliente_ore);
        responsabileInternoOre =(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ResponsabileInternoOre);
        tipologiaRichiestaOre =(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.TipologiaRichiestaOre);
        spinnerOre =(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerOre);
        giornoOre =(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.GiornoOre);
        numeroOre =(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.NumeroOre);
        bt_send_Ore = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.bt_send_Ore);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((Investechblue)activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

and this is my first Implementation of setDateTimeField() with an error:

```
private void setDateTimeField() {
        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        giornoOre.setOnFocusChangeListener((View.OnFocusChangeListener) new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DatePickerStyle,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                giornoOre.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }
        }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
        OreDatePickerDialog.setTitle("");
    }
```

> 04-30 12:45:28.405  13709-13709/com.check.investech_blue.pivetta.investech_blue E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.DatePickerDialog cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnFocusChangeListener
>               at com.check.investech_blue.pivetta.investech_blue.Investechblue$Fragment_ore_permesso.setDateTimeField(Investechblue.java:677)
>               at com.check.investech_blue.pivetta.investech_blue.Investechblue$Fragment_ore_permesso.onCreateView(Investechblue.java:627)
>               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
>               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

and the second solution is:

```
public class ListenerOre implements OnFocusChangeListener {

//gestioneDatapicker
private DatePickerDialog OreDatePickerDialog;
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
public Context c;

public ListenerOre(Context c) {
    super();
    this.c = c;
}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

}
```

}

```
private void setDateTimeField() {
        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        giornoOre.setOnFocusChangeListener((View.OnFocusChangeListener) new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DatePickerStyle,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                giornoOre.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }
        }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
        OreDatePickerDialog.setTitle("");
    }
```

but I don't Know how I can write into ListenerOre..... Anyone can help me? Thanks

Comment: Issue is here `giornoOre.setOnFocusChangeListener((View.OnFocusChangeListener) new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DatePickerStyle,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()` Why do you cast DataPicer to OnFocusChangeListener?

Comment: Because if I don't  cast DataPicer to OnFocusChangeListener I have this Error: OnFocusChangeListener in View cannot be applied to ( android.app.DataPickerDialog)

Comment: But setOnFocusChangeListener can be used for this.. What do you want to do?

Comment: I want that when you clink on the EditText you can chose the date on the Calendar and after this you can see what you have choose on this editText...

Comment: Take a look on my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display `DataPicker` after click on `EditText` change the method `setDataTimeField()` as is shown in the code below:

```
private void setDateTimeField() {
    final Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    giornoOre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DatePickerDialog(TestActity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                            giornoOre.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
                        }
                    },
                    newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    newCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH),
                    newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)).show();
        }
    });
}
```